# Updating existing products via Drupal Migrate

Tags: migrations

I have 2 migrate classes - `ProductsNewMigrate` and `ProductsUpdateMigrate`.

**1)** `ProductsNewMigrate` runs initially, adding products from a CSV file into Drupal.  I can confirm this works correctly, the new products are created and a migrate map is set up in the database.

**2)** `ProductsUpdateMigrate` is required to import another CSV (exactly the same structure as in 1.) but with the updated product data originally migrated via `ProductsNewMigrate`.

I just can't get the Update migrate to work.
I receive the error: 
`array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values`

When looking at the migrate map table for this Migration - `migrate_map_productsupdate`..
I notice `sourceid1` is set to the SKU - which is correct.  However, `destid1` and `destid2` (product_id and product_revision respectively) are both null values - which could be causing this?

Edit: Also receive the warning message: `"product_id" was used as destination field in "sku" mapping but is not in list of destination fields` when viewing the migrate page!

See the code below:

Code:

```
class ProductsUpdateMigration extends CustomMigration {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->description = t('Import new products from CSV');

    $csvfile = "/drupal/products_updated.csv";
    $columns = array(
      0 => array('sku', 'Product SKU'),
      1 => array('title', 'Product title'),
      2 => array('colour_specific', 'Product colour specific'),
      3 => array('price_group', 'Price Group'),
      4 => array('composition', 'Product Composition'),
      5 => array('width', 'Width'),
      8 => array('price', 'Product Price'),
    );

    $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
      array(
        'sku' => array(
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => 255,
          'not null' => TRUE,
          'description' => 'SKU/newref',
          'alias' => 'p',
        )
      ),
      MigrateDestinationEntityAPI::getKeySchema('commerce_product')
    );
    $this->source = new MigrateSourceCSV($csvfile, $columns, array('header_rows' => 1));
    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationEntityAPI('commerce_product', 'blinds');
    $this->systemOfRecord = Migration::DESTINATION;

    // print_r($this);

    // Mapped fields
    $this->addFieldMapping('product_id', 'sku')
      ->sourceMigration('ProductsNew');
    $this->addFieldMapping('title', 'title');
    $this->addFieldMapping('commerce_stock')
      ->defaultValue(5);
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_blinds_colour_specific', 'colour_specific');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_blinds_composition', 'composition');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_blinds_width', 'width');
    $this->addFieldMapping('commerce_price', 'price');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_blinds_price_group', 'price_group');
    $this->addFieldMapping('type')
      ->defaultValue('blinds');
  }

  public function prepareRow($current_row) {
    $colours = explode(';', $current_row->colour_specific);
    // // print '<pre>';
    // // print_r($colours);
    // // print '</pre>';
    $current_row->colour_specific = $colours;
    // $current_row->migrate_map_destid1 = 62;
    // $current_row->migrate_map_destid2 = 67;
    print_r($current_row);
    return TRUE;
  }

  public function prepare($entity, stdClass $row) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Just saying: Normally you should only have one migration, which automatically decides whether to create a new entity or update an existing entity.

Answer (score 1):

Took a slightly different approach to solve this.

1. Upgraded Migrate module from version 2.5 to 2.6
2. Ran upgrades `drush updatedb`, made sure the migration groups were registered (did this via migrate ui)
3. After reading the following articles regarding the new 'trackchanges' hash value option:
   http://timonweb.com/using-hash-value-trackchanges-to-detect-source-data-changes-in-migrate-for-drupal-7
   & http://www.acquia.com/blog/migrate-26-framework-changes I now
   applied the following to the migrate in step 1):

   ```
   $this->source = new MigrateSourceCSV($csvfile, $columns, array(
     'header_rows' => 1,
     'track_changes' => 1
   ));
   ```

The use of track changes now allows the same CSV to be uploaded, any new rows will create a product. Any changes will be detected via the hash that this option provides in the migrate_map table - thus causing the particular product to be updated.